# When I change the Python version, the version in the system does not change

Tags: python, pyenv, virtual-environment, pyenv-virtualenv

I have a problem which is related to system python version vs global/local python version. I use Python version manager, my purpose here is to create a virtual environment and use different Python versions in different projects.

```
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro ~ % python --version
Python 3.9.6
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro ~ % which python
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro ~ % pyenv versions
  system
  3.10.13
* 3.11.7 (set by /Users/birolakanesen/.pyenv/version)
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro ~ % which pyenv
/opt/homebrew/bin/pyenv
```

But I'm having a problem here. The Python version that the system sees appears to be different from the local Python version that I changed via Pyenv. I expected it to look the same on a project by project basis.

```
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro Projects % pyenv local 3.10
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro Projects % python --version
Python 3.9.6
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro Projects % python --version
Python 3.9.6
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro Projects % pyenv versions
  system
* 3.10.13 (set by /Users/birolakanesen/Projects/.python-version)
  3.11.7
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro Projects % 
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro Projects % which python
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3
birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro Projects % which pyenv
```

When I change the Python version on the local side, how can I see the version I changed with the `python --version` command?

Comment: `python` is aliased; no path lookup is ever performed to run the version of Python for which `pyenv` created a stub. Run `unalias python` and try again. (Then figure out which shell configuration file defined the alias in the first place and edit it.)

Comment: `which -a python` should show you *all* the possible commands named `python`.

Comment: Yes, when i run unalias python, version knowledge doesn't show anymore. I run 'brew install python' again, then see the python version, get a 'python not found'.

Comment: Looks like "birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro ~ % which -a python"
python not found
"birolakanesen@Birols-MacBook-Pro ~ % python --version"
zsh: command not found: python

Comment: Got it, unalias python then check the homebrew directory. 'run the echo "alias python=/Users/birolakanesen/.pyenv/shims/python"  >> ~/.zshrc ' this command. Problem solved! Thank you.

Comment: Don't alias `python` at all. `pyenv` should modify your `PATH` variable so that the correct shim is found during command lookup *before* any other version of Python you might have installed.